# is it possible to skip junit tests in ant build script?

Tags: ant

I downloaded a large project that uses ant to build and it runs an extensive number of junit tests each time after compilation. Is there a way to by pass all those tests without changing every individual build file?

Comment: Why would you want to skip the tests?

Comment: because the tests in this particular project takes 10 mins to run, and at this point I am just trying to add print statements to the code.

Comment: How you do it depends on how the build script is written.  There isn't a generic answer.

Comment: Jeanne is correct. You need to edit the ANT script and remove dependencies on the ANT task that runs the tests. (and hope that another task doesn't depend on the tests being run first....)

Comment: Unlike Maven, an Ant script is heavily handcoded. Maven has very well defined project lifecycles and numerous plugins to get chores done with little or no customziation. Whereas in Ant, right from what targets you will have and how they depend on each other needs to be defined in the XML for each Ant build script you write, from scratch. So it depedent on particular script how a target can be muted, in a Maven project you will just add -DskipTests to command and tests are gone.

Answer (score 6):

Any decent ANT build file should have [well defined execution targets that can be called individually](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html) and declare dependencies to other targets if needed, basically something like this:

```
<project default="unitTests">

    <target name="clean">
        <echo message="Cleaning..." />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="clean">
        <echo message="Compiling..." />
    </target>

    <target name="unitTests" depends="compile">
        <echo message="Testing..." />
    </target>

</project>
```

The default target (specified in the `<project>` tag) is usually the most comprehensive task that compiles the project and ensures integrity of the application by also running unit tests.

If your project's build file is constructed like that, then it's a matter of running ANT with the compile target and that will skip the tests. If it isn't built like that then there is no other way than to change the build file and separate the unit tests into it's own target that is not the default.